# How to Get Head Tracking Output Cordinates?

Tags: c#, vb.net, 2d, tracking, construct-2

Anyone know a binary that exports the output of the coordinates? I am looking for something related to several days, I have already visited dozens of sites, downloaded dozens of projects and researched dozens of tutorials, but I can't find anything that really works, I'm trying to create an application similar to **VTuber** (Virtual Youtubers) in *Construct 2* where Head Tracking is crucial to make movement work, I understand the complexity of developing such an engine, but I also imagine that there is something easily accessible out there on the internet, for example...

I found this website that in the lower right corner has the information I would need, but it is a website, it is not quite a binary that I keep monitoring the output to make the character animate inside Construct 2...

**Site**: https://www.visagetechnologies.com/HTML5/latest/Samples/ShowcaseDemo/ShowcaseDemo.html

I also found a very cool project, but it is also a website, although I really liked it because it is very light running.

**Site**: https://www.auduno.com/clmtrackr/examples/clm_emotiondetection.html

I also found a project called "ARKitFaceTracker" but it was made for Unity and the level of complexity of the project is discouraging for me.

Currently a project already exists that uses "**ARKitFaceTracker**" is **PrprLive**, it was made at Unity and it would be perfect if you exported the horns in a text file, so that you could try to make a lighter version and in my own way, but I just I know how to program in *VB.Net* and a little bit of *C#*, but this "Face Camera" was basically what I wanted, but in a way I just used it as "engine", to get the direction coordinates of the head.

[image]

**In short**: basically what I'm looking for is a binary executable that can export the only the movement (left, right, up and down) coordinates of this "Head Tracking" so I can pull this "Output" (txt or json) through Construct 2 and make it animate in real time. I really wanted to make it happen, mainly because I have been researching and searching the internet for several days and it has been a few hours since I crashed and I came here wanting to know if you could help me to continue, because I really don't know what else do, thank you very much.

Comment: Just to clarify.  Is your problem actually "Exporting" the movements, or is it actually "Capturing" the movements?  Dumping the movements out to a txt or json file is relatively simple to do an not really something I would of thought requires a external binary.  If it is the export, can you update your question with the data definition of a Movement and I'm sure we can help

Answer (score 0):

It can be easier if you modify from projects like this:

- https://github.com/1996scarlet/OpenVtuber
- https://github.com/virtuber/openvtuber

Both these solutions separate the face tracking module and the visualization module. It should be easy for you to set up the python servers and request coordinates from them.